# Creating and saving files in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, file-io, savefiledialog

I need to create and write to a .dat file. I'm guessing that this is pretty much the same process as writing to a .txt file, but just using a **different extension**.

In plain english I would like to know how to:

-Create a .dat file

-Write to it

-And save the file using `SaveFileDialog`

There are a few pages that I've been looking at, but I think that my best explanation will come from this site because it allows me to state exactly what I need to learn.

The following code is what I have at the moment. Basically it opens a `SaveFileDialog` window with a blank `File:` section. Mapping to a folder and pressing save does not save anything because there is no file being used. Please help me use this to save files to different locations.

```
Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
dlg.FileName = "";
dlg.DefaultExt = "";

Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

if (result == true)
{
    string filename = dlg.FileName;
}
```

Pages that I've been looking at:

-http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx

-http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cd0b129f-adf1-4c4f-9096-f0662772c821/how-to-use-savefiledialog-for-save-text-file

-http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It depends on what you understand by .dat . If it's really a text file with a different file extension, it's as simple as creating a text file with a .dat extension. If you're expecting a binary format, you might want to look at serialisation depending on your use.

Comment: I think it's the first thing that you said (text file with different extension), because you should be able to read it in Notepad.

Comment: Ah, in that case it's exactly the same as usual procedure, just give a filename with your extension. The system doesn't care what extension you give. You could have a .abc or .a12 file if you wish.

Comment: Soo, why aren't we using .txt, again?

Comment: @Akane Because the program that receives this file needs to receive a .dat

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that the `SaveFileDialog` only yields a filename but does not actually save anything.

```
var sfd = new SaveFileDialog {
    Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*",
    // Set other options depending on your needs ...
};
if (sfd.ShowDialog() == true) { // Returns a bool?, therefore the == to convert it into bool.
    string filename = sfd.FileName;
    // Save the file ...
}
```

Use the filename you are getting from the `SaveFileDialog` and do the following:

```
File.WriteAllText(filename, contents);
```

That's all if you intend to write text to the file.

You can also use:

```
File.WriteAllLines(filename, contentsAsStringArray);
```

Comment: Isn't `ShowDialog` just used to display the `SaveFileDialog` window? I don't think that I receive any filename from it.

Comment: After the user has selected a file in the `SaveFileDialog` and the result is `true`, the `FileName` property contains the full path of the selected file.

Comment: So all `SaveFileDialog` really does is gets a `FileName` and specifies a location to save it?

Comment: Yes, the `SaveFileDialog` really only gets a `FileName`! There are may ways to actually create a file in .NET.

Comment: The `SaveFileDialog` cannot save the file, since it has no idea of what content of this file should be.

Answer (score 0):

```
using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename , true))
{
  writer.WriteLine("whatever your text is");
}
```